# Find Query for Mongo DB string Format Date mm/yy/dd

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query

I have a date column in Mongo as String mm/dd/yyyy format.

I tried :

```
db.testcoll.find( { testdate: "11/23/2019" } );
```

error :

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=pli_premium_db.testcollTree: testdate $eq \"11/23/2019\"\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n No query solutions",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1613587367, 2)
}
```

how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

From [a MongoDB JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13520?focusedCommentId=542209&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-542209),

> the "no query solutions" error message happens because
>
> 1. there are no indexed solutions available for the $exists query, and
> 2. collection scans are disallowed by the notablescan option

I think one of the directions for troubleshooting your problem is that your should check the existence of your `testdate` field in your `testcollTree` collection and `pli_premium_db` database. Please also check the correctness of names of collection and database.